# Inequalities of $H^s$-norm, $(s=0,1)$ $\|v\|^2_s \leq \sqrt2 \|v\|_{s-1}\|v\|_{s+1}$ when $v\in H^{s+1}(\Omega) \cap H_0^1(\Omega)$

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I'd like to show the two following inequalities:

For $s=0,1$, for all $v$ in $H^{s+1}(\Omega) \cap H_0^1(\Omega)$:
$\|v\|^2_s \leq \sqrt2 \|v\|_{s-1}\|v\|_{s+1}$.

I recall that $H^{-1}(\Omega)=(H^1_0(\Omega))'$ and $\|v\|_{-1}=\sup_{w \in H^1_0(\Omega)} \frac{(v,w)_{L^2}}{\|w\|_1}.$

I don't have much idea yet, so I'd appreciate some help. For $s=1$, I've been thinking of dividing my space $\Omega$ into a triangular mesh $g$, so that I get:
$\|v\|^2_{H^1(\Omega)}=\sum_{\tau \in g} \|v\|^2_{H^1(\tau)}=\sum_{\tau \in g} \frac{\lvert \tau \rvert}{\lvert \hat{\tau} \rvert}\|\hat{v}\|^2_{H^1(\tau)}=2\sum_{\tau \in g} \lvert \tau \rvert \|\hat{v}\|^2_{H^1(\hat{\tau})}$,

where $\hat{\tau}$ is the reference triangles of vertices $\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $\hat{v}$ is the tranformation of $v$ onto $\hat{\tau}$.

This makes a 2 pop, which is a good sign, but still I don't know how to continue. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about the $\sqrt 2$? After removing the square on the LHS, you're saying the inequality has a $2^{1/4}$?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it was wrong, but that's how the inequality is stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $s=0$, we have
$$ \|v\|_{0}^2 = (v,v)_{L^2} = \|v\|_1 \frac{(v,v)_{L^2}}{\|v\|_1} \le \|v\|_1 \sup_{0\neq w\in H^1_0} \frac{(v,w)_{L^2}}{\|w\|_1} = \|v\|_1\|v\|_{-1}.$$
For $s=1$, I can get a constant that depends on the dimension $d$ by elementary means. This constant depends on the choice of Sobolev norm; if you choose $\|v\|_k=\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \|D^\alpha v\|_0$ then the below gives the constant 1. Since $v|_{\partial \Omega}=0,$
$$ \|\nabla v\|_{0}^2 = \int_{\Omega} \nabla v\cdot\nabla v dx = -\int_{\Omega}(\Delta v)v dx \le \|\Delta v\|_0\|v\|_0,$$
Hence
$$ \|v\|_1^2 = \|v\|_0^2 + \|\nabla v\|_ 0^2 \le (\|v\|_0 + \|\Delta v\|_0 )\|v\|_0 \le \sqrt{2d} \|v\|_2\|v\|_0$$
where we used
\begin{align} \|\Delta v\|_0^2  
&=  \int_{\Omega} \Big|\sum_{i=1}^d \partial_i^2v\Big|^2 dx \le d\int_{\Omega}\sum_{i=1}^d|\partial_i^2 v|^2dx, \end{align}
so that
(with $a+b\le\sqrt 2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$)
$$ \| v\|_0+\|\Delta v\|_0\le \sqrt2\sqrt{\| v\|_0^2+\|\Delta v\|_0^2} \le \sqrt{2d}\sqrt{\sum_{|\alpha|\le 2} \|D^\alpha v\|_0^2}=\sqrt{2d}\|v\|_2.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Calvin Khor!!

Comment: @FlorianSpicher you're welcome; if you ever figure out the correct version of the question (or you know how to prove the result with $\sqrt2$ instead of $\sqrt{2d}$) please tell me!

Comment: I will, I'll think about it during the week.

Comment: @FlorianSpicher you can improve the constant to $\sqrt{d+1}$ if you only use $|\sum_{i=1}^K a_i|\le \sqrt K (\sum a_i^2)^{1/2}$ once:$$ \int \Delta v v  = \sum_i \int \partial_i^2 v v  \le \sum_i \|\partial_i^2 v\|_0 \|v\|_0$$ and then you sum with the $\|v\|_0^2$ term, and only now use the above inequality. But I don't see a way to avoid it completely. And yet I can't find a counterexample or show it is sharp

Comment: Thanks! We came up with this inequality too and may have found a counterexample with $u(x,y)=(1-x^2)(1-y^2)$ on $\Omega=[-1,1]^2$. The inequality doesn't hold for $\sqrt{2}$ but it does for $\sqrt{3}$, that is for $\sqrt{d+1}$. We should get a solution from a PhD student any time now. I keep you posted, as promised!

Comment: @FlorianSpicher Well that's convenient if true. Why is it? I'll give it another go later; thanks for the updates!

Comment: Well, we’re debating at the moment on some points but all in all it seems the point is that, in your last inequality we could just say $(\|v\|_0 + \| \Delta v\|_0)^2 \leq 2* \| v\|^2_2$, so that we don’t have to include some coefficient depending on $d$.

Plus, we seem to have messed up with our counterexample.

Comment: There are many things to show actually, but using twice the partial integration we can show that the $H^2$-semi-norm is in fact equal to the $L^2$-norm of the Laplacian. We have to use the fact that the derivatives in fact also have to be zero on the boundary and since the functions aren’t $C^3$, one could use the density to exchange the order of integration. Then it’s just Jensen’s inequality.

Comment: I'll update the answer to have that when I have time. But I must apologise because I'm pretty sure I've seen that before...!

Comment: Please don’t apologize, that was really helpful :)! Thanks again!